# Get String from Parse.com and setting it into UILabel (iOs Swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

As a newbie Swift developer I’m got stucked with reading data from Parse.com and setting it into UILabel.

I’ve done simple application which fecths multiple rows of data from Parse.com. Everything seems to work as should, I can see array contains right data, I can read and use cells like createdAt etc. The problem is when I try to read value created by my own code and use it as  UIlabel text, I can't get value out from PFObject. I can print it to console, and if I try to debug I can see that object contains right data, I just can't get it set into UILabel.

What should I do to get value and set it e.g. into UILabel as tried below?

> let prediction: PFObject = self.timelineData[indexPath.row] as PFObject
>
> println( prediction.valueForKey("prediction") )
>      // This prints :  Optional(( "Saved String as it should be" ))
>
> cell.prediction.text = prediction.valueForKey("prediction") as? NSString
>      // But inserting same text to UILabel.text fails (label is empty)

Thanks,

J

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is:

```
if let prediction = self.timelineData[indexPath.row] as PFObject?{
   if let myString = prediction.valueForKey("prediction") as? NSArray {
      cell.prediction.text = myString.firstObject! as? String
   }
}
```